# Django / OnetoMany relation within the same class

Tags: django

Here is my models.py

```
class Scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField('Scene name', max_length=60,unique=True)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Scene date')

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   
 description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    previous = models.OneToOneField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='next',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

I have started with one instance : Scene1

The problem is I want to have **on to many** choices and not **one to one** like explained below

[image]

Nevertheless, When I change to

```
previous = models.ManyToManyField(
```

Then I also get an error about **on_delete** :

*TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'*

What would be the best djangonic way ?

Comment: `ManyToManyField` doesn't accept the `on_delete` argument. Only `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your requirements are:

- One scene can have **only one previous scene**
- One scene can have **many next scenes**

You are almost there. Instead of `OneToOneField`, use `ForeignKey` with `self` reference:

```py
previous = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', ...)
```

Comment: In the case of the next scene, (one to many) can I use also the same relationship ?

Comment: @fransua You can access the next scenes of the current scene using `scene.next.all()`.